# Im currently using Ubuntu 20.04 and wifi not showing any network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

this is iwconfig result -

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx00e0222de1fe  unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

result of lshw -C network config

```
sudo lshw -C  network

  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@5:1
       logical name: wlx00e0222de1fe
       serial: 00:e0:22:2d:e1:fe
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.15.0-41-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

lsusb

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:006a Wacom Co., Ltd CTE-460 [Bamboo One Pen (S)]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Are you asking about a USB dongle?

Comment: no,  the dongle was working fine today morning

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: Is this a laptop?

Comment: added lsub output

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list this command doesn't show any output

Comment: i am using desktop

Comment: Please follow the procedure at the duplicate.